# how to design returned json data from mysql php

Tags: php, mysql, json

How to get JSON data like this:

[image]

NOT like THIS:

[image]

Comment: What have you tried within notepad to reformat this block of text?  You will always receive better responses when you offer actual text in your question versus dropping in screenshots.  Your two images are completely unrelated - one is talking about nm-cty-hse-yrs the other is id-UserName-Password-Email.  You have not provided the necessary input and desired output to fully/accurately answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON data **is** like the desired output, it's just not neatly formatted. You don't need to worry, as it will still be executed the exact same way by your scripts.

If you'd like to copy 'pretty' JSON as text, you can format it online with tools such as **[JSONFormatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/)** or [**JSONLint**](https://jsonlint.com/).

If you're accessing your JSON as a URL such as `/file.json`, you **cannot** format it, and it will also look like your second example. Having said that, you can use browser plugins like [**JSONView**](http://benhollis.net/software/jsonview/) to 'prettify' it for you.

You can also **output** 'pretty' JSON to the DOM with PHP by using the `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT` optional parameter of **[json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php)**:

```
echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: My browser, Firefox, formats JSON very nicely. Could be native Firefox, could be a plugin. But still: data is data, it is not meant for humans to read. edit: it is a plugin named Json-View

Comment: @IvoP -- Thanks for the suggestion; added JSONView as another way to format JSON :)